Extracting and analyzing data from numpy histogram
I need to loop through the bins of a histogram and extract the data to perform a series of calculations with the data.
I've attempted extracting the data and setting up my loop with those variables but it isn't quite as streamlined or effective as i would like, i also just tried using a variable for the histogram data itself to no avail. For clarity i will ultimately be analyzing multiple histograms and graphing the results of the analysis I'm just struggling with the syntax as I don't have any formal python training. If i need to provide more information please let me know.

Can you post your existing code for analyzing a histogram, and give an example of a problem you want to solve?
